# Javascript Literal Object Notation This vs Object Name

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-literal

I have an object literal like this:

```
var test = {
    one: function() {
    },
    two: function() {
        this.one(); // call 1
        test.one(); // call 2
    }
};
```

What is the difference between the calls in the `two` function (using the object literal name versus using `this`)?

Comment: `this` is a keyword. Highly consider reading a tutorial (or searching SO) to find out "what it does". (`test` is merely a variable which is presumed to be closured, but it *could* be a global property -- e.g. an alias for `window.test` -- in that case.)

Comment: Ah, I am curious why it shows up in Eclipse intellisense/autocomplete.. it's confusing. I corrected this in my question, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test` is always bound within the closure of the `two` function to the variable `test` whereas `this` depends on how the function is called. If the function is called using the regular object member access syntax, `this` becomes the object owning the function:

```
test.two(); // inside, "this" refers to the object "test"
```

You can change the value of `this` by using `Function.prototype.call`:

```
test.two.call(bar); // inside, "this" refers to the object "bar"
```

But the value of `test` remains the same inside the `two` function, regardless of how the function is invoked.

Comment: Thanks! Is there another way to bind an object to the this keyword aside from using Function.call() - i.e. can it happen from the calling context?

Comment: Another way is `Function.prototype.apply`, which is quite similar to `call`. Yet another way is to copy the function reference to a property of another object and to call it as a member of the new object: `var bar = { two: test.two }; bar.two(); // this will be bar`

Comment: Yet another way is to assign the function to a local variable and call it from that variable: `var two = test.two; two(); // this will be the global object`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the second call will always be bound to the test object, whereas this might be rebound to some other object:

```
var other = {
    one: function () {
        alert('other.one');
    }
};

// call test.two as a method of object other
test.two.call(other); // calls other.one and test.one
```