# Javascript member accessor by this/classname

Tags: javascript, constructor

What is the difference between this two constructs?

```
function ObjectName()
{
    this.member1 = "foo"; // #1
    ObjectName.member2 = "baz"; #2
}
```

Is it just two ways of saying the same thing, or the members declared the second way have some different properties? Does it work differently on inherited objects?

Comment: Take a look to : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9092288/3315914

Comment: [I think they're different, indeed](http://jsfiddle.net/VFAA6/)

Answer (score 1):

It does two different things.

```
this.member1 = "foo":
```

Sets the member1 property on the created instance of the object, when called with new

```
new ObjectName().member1 === 'foo';
```

Setting the property on the function only sets in on the function object

```
ObjectName.member2 = 'baz';
ObjectName.member2 === 'baz';
myObjInstance.member2 === undefined
```

That's because the function keyword really sets up a variable, it is shorthand for:

```
var ObjectName = function() {
```

And as an object you can set any properties you want, but it's only on that object itself.

Comment: Do you mean that the member2 is a private member? So, if I call obj.SomeFunc(), will member2 be available? in the SomeFunc() scope?

Comment: member2 will only exist on the ObjectName object, not on any instances you create.  member1 is an instance member because it's within the scope of the function (constructor so to speak).  To get a private member use var myprivate = 'abc' instead of this, so that it is in the function scope but not exposed externally.

Comment: True, but very complicated way to say that member2 is a private static member.

Comment: It's NOT a static member.  It only exists on the ObjectName object, which will be in-scope to anything created in the same scope.  If ObjectName (your constructor function) is in the global scope than it will be accessible to everything else - without requiring any type of instance of your object.  It's how you accomplish name-spaced properties, no differnt than var config = { member2: 'baz' };

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Matt, but In short, I would say the first one(member1) is an instance property, the second(member2) is a static property, if you are familiar with OOP.

Comment: Not only static, but private, it seems.

Comment: no, its not private. anyone who can get ObjectName will be able to get the value of ObejectName.member2.